# flex chat/telnet application send/receive same window in TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, console, textarea, chat, telnet

Just wanting to know if anybody has seen an example of a telnet/chat or other console like FLEX application where you can use the same TextArea as input/ouput area.

I've been trying to modify the app at:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/17_Networking_and_communications_8.html

but so far, computer says no.

All the implementations I've seen use a combination of TextInput and TextArea.

The challenge is that we'll be using this app to telnet into some old routers and we'll need to do a fair amount of copy/pasting. Based on what I've seen, it seems that I would need to point the mouse into the TextInput in order to be able to right click and paste, which is not very sleak.....

Your thoughts, 
Fran

Answer (score 0):

*edit* Just realized that I had trimmed out what was directly pertaining to the question: I was unable to find anything that used the TextArea for input and output; see the below suggestions if custom-component suggestions are ok.

The TextArea component only fires a [change](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/Event.html#CHANGE) event whenever a **user** adds input. Whenever you set the text field *programmatically*, a change event does not fire--you could maybe use that as a way to know what is user input and console "responses" by looking for carriage-returns (`\r`).

I'm unsure if you have a requirement to maintain the user's input at the bottom-most line (like a console), even after the console responds with something like auto-complete. If that's the case, then something a bit more complex would have to come into play (such as remembering where the user's input started/ended) or the requirement of a single-component console needs to be reconsidered--sleek is nice, but not always necessary.